# Teradata Case When statement - replacing values not in 1 column in result

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have two tables and want to combine them where if not in one column it will be added to the other column. That way if they match except for where column 1 does not contain name in column 1 an 'N/A' will appear and same for column 2.

I get the names to match for rows that are present and get the 'N/A' to appear in column 2 where there is no match. I cannot get more rows added to column 1 where there is no match. I have 800 rows in total in Column 1 and 330 match in column 2. In column 2 there are 30, that are not in column 1.

So I want to get a list of the 800 + 30 = 830 rows total. 30 being N/A in column 1.

Thanks for the help.  I have looked here and other places but nothing seems to match or come close or I just not getting it.

```
SELECT  
  CASE 
    WHEN cc.Db_Name = dr.DB_NAME THEN cc.DatabaseName
    WHEN cc.DatabaseName <> dr.DBE_NAME THEN 'n/a'
    ELSE cc.Db_Name
  END AS SQL_DB_NAME
  , CASE 
    WHEN cc.Db_Name = dr.DB_NAME THEN dr.DATABASE_NAME
    WHEN cc.Db_Name <> dr.DB_NAME THEN 'zz'
    ELSE 'N/A'
  END AS DG_DB_NAME
FROM DL_SCANS1 AS cc -- (column1)
LEFT JOIN DG_SCAN AS dr -- (column2)
  ON dr.DB_NAME = cc.DB_Name AND dr.Table_View = 'TABLE'
GROUP BY cc.Db_Name, dr.DB_NAME
```

Result:

```
SQL_DB_NAME DG_DB_NAME  
AAA         AAA  
BBB         BBB  
CCC         N/A  
N/A         DDD
```

total of 830 rows

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you are trying to do, please show some sample data and desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my understanding of what you're trying to do:

- you have two tables with data that you want to "consolidate"
- `DL_SCAN1` has 800 "good" values which you want to return in `Column 1`
- `DG_SCAN` has 30 "good" values which you want to return in `Column 2`
- you want to return the 830 rows, but your current query only returns 800 rows

If this is the case, then the reason is because you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`.  This will take all 800 rows in the "left" table (`DL_SCAN1`) and combine them with the matching rows in the "right" table (`DG_SCAN`) that have the same `DB_NAME` values.  Any other unmatched rows, from `DG_SCAN` will be discarded.

Try changing the `LEFT JOIN` to a `FULL OUTER JOIN` which will also include the unmatched rows from `DG_SCAN` and that should give you your missing 30 rows.

```
FULL OUTER JOIN DG_SCAN AS dr -- (column2)
  ON dr.DB_NAME = cc.DB_Name AND dr.Table_View = 'TABLE'
```

More info on joins in Teradata: [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/teradata/teradata_joins.htm)

Comment: Thank you for the help! It worked. Sorry for late response.

Comment: Woohoo! Happy to help :)